# How do I render high quality monochrome text with SDL2_TTF?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm writing a game with old school low resolution graphics. I'm using SDL2_TTF to render monochrome text but it doesn't seem to be hinted properly. I set the hinting with `TTF_SetFontHinting(font, TTF_HINTING_MONO)` and rendered the text with all three rendering functions (`TTF_RenderText_Solid`, `TTF_RenderText_Shaded` and `TTF_RenderText_Blended`) but I'm not happy with the results. Here's the output I'm getting from `TTF_RenderText_Solid`. The other functions output antialiased text.

[image: Actual output]

And here's the output I want. This is Andale Mono 12pt (same as above) rendered by the Mac Terminal emulator and scaled up 4x.

[image: Expected output]

The quality of the output does matter because the text is scaled up 4x when shown to the player. Why are they different? I thought that FreeType was the de-facto font rendering library so SDL2_TTF and Terminal would both be using it.

Am I simply using the SDL2_TTF library incorrectly?

Comment: What do the other hinting modes look like?

Comment: Changing the hinting mode seems to have no effect on the output

Comment: How was your FreeType built?  With/without the (recently un)patented Truetype bytecode interpreter?

Comment: I'm not using FreeType directly so I don't know

Comment: Actually, changing the hinting mode does change the text slightly but the quality is still less than Mac Terminal

Comment: You could try rebuilding SDL2_ttf with the latest TrueType version. If all else fails, you could render your text with `*_Blended` and then make it monochrome with an appropriate custom alpha threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to mess with the SDL2_TTF library to achieve the effect I was looking for so I decided to find a different font that looks better. I found that if I chose a [font that looks pixelated](http://www.fontriver.com/font/grand9k_pixel/) and render it at just the right point size everything looks fine.

[image: The effect I was looking for]

Comment: Always use a real "Pixel Font" when you want to render pixelated text. These fonts are designed to be rendered at a specific point size to perfectly fit on the native pixels of the screen. You can only render these at 1x 2x 3x etc or they will not look right. If you specifically want pixel fonts with SDL, it is almost easier to just render rectangles from a bitmap font. By the way, you can find some nice free ones on the Dwarf Fortress website: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/Tileset_repository.